# Round brackets enclosing private variables. Why used in this case?

Tags: perl

I am reading [Learning Perl 6th edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do), and the subroutines chapter has this code:

```
foreach (1..10) {
  my($square) = $_ * $_; # private variable in this loop
  print "$_ squared is $square.\n";
}
```

Now I understand that the list syntax, ie the brackets, are used to distinguish between list context and scalar context as in:

```
my($num) = @_; # list context, same as ($num) = @_;
my $num = @_; # scalar context, same as $num = @_;
```

But in the foreach loop case I can't see how a list context is appropriate.

And I can change the code to be:

```
foreach (1..10) {
  my $square = $_ * $_; # private variable in this loop
  print "$_ squared is $square.\n";
}
```

And it works exactly the same.  So why did the author use my($square) when a simple my $square could have been used instead?

Is there any difference in this case?

Comment: I'd say "Ask the author". In this case the parenthesis are superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're quite correct. It's redundant. It doesn't make any difference in this case, because you're *effectively* forcing a list context to list context operation.

E.g.

```
my ( $square ) = ( $_ * $_ );
```

Which also produces the same result. So - in this case, doesn't matter. But is generally speaking not good coding style.

Comment: why is it bad coding style? If you put consistently brackets around `my` declarations, I wouldn't mind.

Comment: It's bad coding style because it causes future maintainers to come here and ask questions like this one.

Comment: You could - technically - do all your variable operations in a list context. It'd work. In many ways - as long as your code is consistent, it's 'ok'. But there's a lot to be said for code clarity - forcing list context when it's not needed will only ever reduce clarity.

Comment: @Sobrique, No, you couldn't. `my ($x) = grep ...;` is different than `my $x = grep ...;`, just to mention one example

Answer (score 5):

Certainly in this case, the brackets aren't necessary. They're not strictly *wrong* in the sense that they do do what the author intends. As with so much in Perl, [there's more than one way to do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

So there's the underlying question: why did the author choose to do this this way? I wondered at first whether it was the author's preferred style: perhaps he chose always to put his lists of new variables in brackets simply so that something like:

```
my ($count) = 4;
```

where the brackets aren't doing anything helpful, at least looked consistent with something like:

```
my ($min, $max) = (2, 3);
```

But looking at the whole book, I can't find a single example of this use of brackets for a single value other than the section you referenced. As one example of many, the **m// in List Context** section in Chapter 9 contains a variety of different uses of `my` with assignments, but does not use brackets with any single values.

I'm left with the conclusion that as the author introduced `my` in subroutines with `my($m, $n);` he tried to vary the syntax as little as possible the next time he used it, ending up with `my($max_so_far)` and then tried to explain scalar and list contexts, as you quoted above. I'm not sure this is terribly helpful.

TL;DR It's not necessary, although it's not *actually* wrong. Probably a good idea to avoid this style in your code.